# Realm is deleted from the WWW-Authenticate header (ASP.NET Core 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, basic-authentication, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5 and IT HIT WebDAV Engine on Windows 10.

I want to test a WebDAV implementation with litmus.
The problem is, litmus expects a value for realm in the WWW-Authenticate header for Basic (Authentication).

On an unauthorized request, the server does the following:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(HeaderNames.Authorization))
    {
        await context.ChallengeAsync();

        // uncomment this to set WWW-Authenticate header (?)
        // context.Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.WWWAuthenticate, "Basic realm=\"MyRealm\"");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The response contains the following headers, among others:

```
...
WWW-Authenticate: Basic
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
```

If I remove the line `await context.ChallengeAsync();` and set only the HTTP StatusCode to 401 instead: `context.Response.StatusCode = 401;`, exactly the same response headers are returned.
This leads me to the question: do I need to call context.ChallengeAsync()? What exactly does this method do? (I thought it would set the WWW-Authenticate headers in the response, but apparently they are set even if I don't call it).

Now when I try to explicitly set the header for "Basic" with the realm, the realm-part gets lost "somehow". The response contains the following headers:

```
...
WWW-Authenticate: Basic
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: Basic
```

(Yes, Basic shows up twice and the realm is missing).

If I neither execute `await context.ChallengeAsync();` nor set `context.Response.StatusCode = 401;`, I get a response which contains the correct header `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="MyRealm"`, but with HTTP StatusCode 200, which is not desired.

How do I add the realm to the WWW-Authenticate header?

Comment: The authentication type should be set in the server, not client.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs

Comment: @jdweng My question is all about an ASP.NET core **server** and how to make it return a 401 response with a WWW-Authenticate header containing a realm. The only client here is litmus, which expects this header to contain a realm.

Comment: Microsoft develops their own custom protocols and do not do a real good job of explaining what they actually do.  See following : https://hamidmosalla.com/2017/03/29/asp-net-core-action-results-explained/?force_isolation=true

Comment: @sawie wondering if you ever got to solve this, as I am facing the same issue where the realm is not getting set?

Comment: @user824910 no, I'm sorry, I never solved it and I gave up on it at some point

Comment: @sawie appreciate you for responding back